# The routing standard when doing CRUD operations on navigation properties in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, routes

I apologize in advanced if this is more of an opinion based question, but I would like to know the standard/convention for the following situation if there is one.

I have a CustomersController that has basic MVC scaffolding crud views. The route format is the typical: Customers/Edit/1

Let's say on the Customers edit view I also want the to list the Customer's contacts with crud on that grid.

So my CustomerViewModel contains all of the typical Customer properties and a navigation property: IEnumerable contacts. This makes listing the contacts at the route: Customers/Edit/1 easy.

My main question is how I should go about doing the CRUD for the contacts through the Customer entity.

1. Should all of my CustomerContact action methods be done inside of the CustomersController or a separate ContactsController? Since everything is through the Customers entity this leads me to believe the CustomersController would be the common choice.
2. Should my routes from edit and delete links on the Contacts listing table within the customer edit page be something like Customers/1/Contacts/Edit/1, Customers/1/Delete/1, and so on.. Or is there a better pattern to follow.

Comment: It's probably pretty opinion-based, but here goes... I would argue that Contacts should have their own controller *if* they are their own aggregate root in the domain.  If, on the other hand, they are properties which describe a Customer and never exist outside the context of a parent Customer object then it makes sense to me that they'd be part of the Customers controller.  It just means that a Customer object is more complex than standard scaffolded CRUD supports, which isn't uncommon.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. So if contacts is a common entity throughout the system and is being used as CustomerContacts, EmployeeContacts, VendorContacts, then you would give it its own controller. Otherwise in my case if it is strictly being used for Customers it should probably all just be handled in the Customers controller. Does my routing look alright for an individual contact edit? Customers/5/Contacts/Edit/1?

Comment: It's not a question of how common it is, but of how singular it is.  (Consider that a "phone number" is also a common attribute, but doesn't need its own controller.)  I'd give it its own controller only if it made sense to edit a Contact, and only a Contact, outside the context of any other entity.  It *sounds* like a Contact isn't itself an entity in the domain, but just a complex value type used as an attribute on a variety of entities (Customer, Employee, etc.).

Comment: Got it, makes complete sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
For the First question :::::::::
```

`ASP.NET` `MVC` invokes different controller classes (and different action methods within  them) depending on the incoming URL. The default URL routing logic used by `ASP.NET`  `MVC` uses a format like this to determine what code to invoke:

```
/[Controller]/[ActionName]/[Parameters]
```

Set the format for routing in the App_Start/RouteConfig.cs  file. App_Start/RouteConfig.cs
So you can make as you want number of controllers
but you should know that you should really know how to links them in the `appstat` file 
that contains the routes
and link it with the appropriate views.

```
For the Second Question :::::::::
```

there are many ways for Passing parameters from the URL to the controller:::
i will give an example for every method this a `wellcome example` 
inside any predefined controller
[image]

1-you can pass it like the default way as  i sayed above ,

and this method is called `path param`

2- you can pass them like this :::

this method is called `query param`
[image]

3- you can mix between the two ways:
[image]

i advise you to start learning from here:::
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started
 even if the mvc version is not the same as it your version

Comment: Elie I appreciate this answer but it doesn't exactly answer my question. I am experienced in how to do everything you mentioned. I was more concerned about handling editing of navigation properties.

Comment: ok , i gave you 3 types of passing params patterns
i think it must be useful